# Как сделать для SVG элемента изменение цвета при клике на кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, svg, анимация, toggle

Обычный `toggleClass` или проверить его `hasClass`?

Суть вопроса ....

Имеем `<rect />` с `width` и `height` `fill` без разницы какой, смысл в том, что при клике на одну и туже кнопку менять `fill` с одного на другой.

**Есть ли такая возможность ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### #1 вариант

Два цвета

```html
<div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  

<rect id="rec" x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="#B34EE9" /> 
<g id="btn">
<rect x="20" y="150" width="100" height="25" rx="5" fill="#D5D5D5" /> 
<text x="30" y="166" font-size="14" fill="black">Change Color</text>
 </g>
    
<script> 
var colorArray = ["#5A9C6E", "#B34EE9"]; // создаем массив с цветами фона
var i = 0; 
 var rect = document.getElementById("rec");
 var button = document.getElementById("btn");
 button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  rect.style.fill = colorArray[i]; 
    i++;
    if( i > colorArray.length - 1){
        i = 0;
    }
});
</script> 
</svg>
</div>
```

### #2 вариант

Несколько цветов

```html
  
<div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  

<rect id="rec" x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" rx="15" fill="purple" /> 
<g id="btn">
<rect x="20" y="150" width="100" height="25" rx="5" fill="#D5D5D5" /> 
<text x="30" y="166" font-size="14" fill="black">Change Color</text>
 </g>
    
<script> 
var colorArray = ["#4B825B", "#A8BF5A", "#C3DE68", "#FA944B", "#B34EE9"]; // создаем массив с цветами фона прямоугольника 
var i = 0; 
 var rect = document.getElementById("rec");
 var button = document.getElementById("btn"); 
  //  Добавляем слушатель события клика по кнопке, при клике перебираем элементы массива
 button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  rect.style.fill = colorArray[i]; 
    i++;
    if( i > colorArray.length - 1){
        i = 0;
    }
});
</script> 
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: это первый подобный пример в сети !  а это подействует на polygon,circle,path ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский абсолютно без разницы, любой svg объект. Давай сделаю третий пример с случайным заполнением цвета, например того же полигона

Comment: вот этот вопрос надо на SO задать ...там все Q&A только на jQuery и все не работают

Answer (score 5):

### Заполнение произвольной части фигуры SVG случайным цветом

В фигуре утенка есть несколько патчей, выбираем произвольный патч, например тело утенка и присваиваем ему `id="duck"`
Этот патч будет закрашиваться случайно выбранным цветом при нажатии на кнопку `id="btn"`

Формирование случайного цвета реализуется :

```
red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
```

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="550" height="400" viewBox="0 0 550 400" >
  <path id="duck"  fill="#FEFE00" d="M133 137c2-1 3-3 3-5 0-15-4-28-12-39 0 0 0-1 0-1 1-9-1-15-7-17 0 0 0-1 0-1 7-31 27-48 60-52 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 0 14 0 21 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 24 4 42 14 53 31 4 6 6 13 8 20 6 29 1 52-12 68 1 1 1 2 2 2 19 3 37 0 54-8 5-3 10-6 13-11 8-11 18-21 30-28 2 0 3 0 4 0 25 17 40 43 45 79 4 28 2 52-7 73 -9 21-22 38-40 51C331 310 309 318 282 320c-62 5-113-1-155-19 -32-14-46-44-44-90 4-31 19-50 47-58 1 0 1-1 2-1 1-1 2-1 3-1 0-4 0-8 0-12C133 137 133 137 133 137zM193 91c0 0-1 0-1 0 -11-4-19-1-23 8 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 7 1 12 4 15 0 0 1 0 1 0 8 4 16 4 22-2 0 0 0-1 0-1C200 103 199 96 193 91z"/>
  <path  fill="#9BC1E9" d="M193 91c5 6 6 13 3 21 0 0 0 1 0 1 -6 6-14 7-22 2 0 0-1 0-1 0 -3-3-5-8-4-15 0 0 0-1 0-1 4-9 12-12 23-8C193 90 193 91 193 91z"/>
  <path  fill="#FF8D10" d="M133 137c0 0-1 0-1 0 -32-5-53-20-63-46 0 0 0-1 0-1 0-1 0-2 0-3 7-3 16-4 25-4 11 1 19-2 23-8 6 2 8 8 7 17 0 0 0 1 0 1 8 11 12 24 12 39C137 134 135 136 133 137z"/>

<g id="btn" transform="translate(-15 -120)">
<rect x="20" y="150" width="100" height="25" rx="5" fill="greenyellow" /> 
<text x="30" y="166" font-size="14" fill="black">Change Color</text>
 </g>
 </svg>   
<script> 

 var rDuck = document.getElementById("duck");
 var button = document.getElementById("btn");
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
   green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  rDuck.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
   });
</script> 

</div>
```

### Заполнение случайным цветом секторов окружности

В этом примере окружность разбита на 6 секторов. Каждый сектор заполняется случайным цветом при нажатии на кнопку, как в примере выше с утенком.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
 var one = document.getElementById("one");
 var two = document.getElementById("two");
 var three = document.getElementById("three");
 var four = document.getElementById("four");
 var five = document.getElementById("five");
 var six = document.getElementById("six");
 
  button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   red = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
   green = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    blue = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
  one.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ red +","+ green+","+blue+")");
  two.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ (red / 0.9) +","+ (green * 0.9)+","+(blue * 0.9)+")");
  three.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ (red * 0.8) +","+ (green / 0.8)+","+(blue * 0.8)+")");
  four.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ (red * 0.7) +","+ (green * 0.7)+","+(blue / 0.7)+")");
  five.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ (red * 0.6) +","+ (green / 0.6)+","+(blue * 0.6)+")");
  six.setAttributeNS(null,"fill","rgb("+ (red / 0.5) +","+ (green * 0.5)+","+(blue * 0.5)+")");
  
   });
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 -20 150 150" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
 <path id="one" d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z' />
  <path id="two" d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z' />
  <path id="three" d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z' />
  <path id="four" d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z' />
  <path id="five" d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z' />
  <path id="six" d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z' />

<g id="btn" transform="translate(0 0)">
<rect x="15" y="-20" width="80" height="20" rx="5" fill="greenyellow" /> 
<text x="22" y="-7" font-size="12" fill="black">Change Color</text>
 </g>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Саша я вообще вопрос не для себя создал .... тот вопрос проигнорировали все ..а он интересный

Comment: @МаксимЛенский ты же в комментариях спросил - можно ли таким образом, как в первом ответе заливать цветом любые элементы SVG? Вот этот мой ответ, как раз на эту тему. Если я что-то не понял, объясни в чате

Comment: ок щас зайду ...

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, как вы это делаете? Пытался выучить svg но не как не получается. Не раз видел как вы отвечали на подобные вопросы. Пожалуйста, если не сложно, подскажите хороший ресурс для изучение svg

Answer (score 4):

Оптимизированный сниппет @Alexandr'a:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var paths = document.getElementsByClassName("path");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
    paths[i].setAttribute("fill", "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")");
  }
});
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 -20 150 150" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <path class="path" d='M55,55 L105,55 A50,50 0 0,1 80,98.30z'/>
  <path class="path" d='M55,55 L80,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 30,98.30z'/>
  <path class="path" d='M55,55 L30,98.30 A50,50 0 0,1 5,55z'/>
  <path class="path" d='M55,55 L5,55 A50,50 0 0,1 30,11.69z'/>
  <path class="path" d='M55,55 L30,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 80,11.69z'/>
  <path class="path" d='M55,55 L80,11.69 A50,50 0 0,1 105,55z'/>
  <g id="btn" transform="translate(0 0)">
    <rect x="15" y="-20" width="80" height="20" rx="5" fill="greenyellow"/> 
    <text x="22" y="-7" font-size="12" fill="black">Change Color</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: очень хороший ответ, благодарю